# Shell command only working if executed manually but not from Python file

Tags: python, shell, command-line, subprocess

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am using Python to automate some tasks. I wrote a simple script that creates multiple users at once using the [`newusers`](https://www.tecmint.com/create-multiple-user-accounts-in-linux/) command. `newusers` reads a file containing the users' data and creates new users based on that data. 
What I first do in my script, is create a file called `users.txt` in which I put all the user data. After that, I call `newusers` on that file later in my script in order to actually make the users.

I tried using both the os and subprocess module in order to call the command `sudo newusers users.txt`, however, both did not work. The command, however, does work when I run it directly from the command line.

Here I tried to execute the command using subprocess:

```
create_users = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'newusers', 'users.txt'], shell=True)
```

Here I tried using os:

`os.system('sudo newusers users.txt')`

I even tried to create an external file which would then call the command:

```
make_users = open('make_users.py', 'x')

make_users.write('#!/usr/bin/env python3\n\n\
import os\n\n\
os.system(\'sudo newusers users.txt\')')

os.system('python3 make_users.py')
```

[This](https://pastebin.com/SNxDsLhN) is the link to the entire code.

The problem is that when I run `sudo newusers users.txt` manually, (directly from the command line) the command works perfectly fine. The only time it does not work is when I run it from my Python script.

I was thinking that maybe, the script needs to successfully exit before I am able to run `sudo newusers users.txt`

I do not get any sort of error, in fact, the output of the subprocess is `None`. But when I check `/etc/passwd` no users were created.

Of course, I could simply run the script (which would create the `users.txt`) and then just run `sudo newusers users.txt` directly from the command line, but I want to understand what the problem is and why I am not able to execute that same command using Python.

PS: Permissions are not a problem since I am root.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Why would you run `sudo` if you are root?

Comment: I know I don't need to but it doesn't really make a difference... (It just came like that though, no specific reason.)

Comment: I don't understand why your "os.system" call does not work. Your Popen call however seems to be wrong. As far as I know, you should either use "subprocess.Popen('sudo newusers users.txt', shell=True)" or preferably "subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'newusers', 'users.txt'])"

Comment: Why the second one preferably? Are they different?

Comment: In this case probably not, however -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

Comment: `os.system` reports errors (such as it does) simply by returning a number; don’t ignore it.  But `subprocess` is much better anyway, unless you pass a list and `shell=True` which passes the arguments to the shell *instead* of to the command named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. When I created the `users.txt` file, I did not close it. As mentioned in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iba-I4CrmyA&t=487s, closing the file will: 'return the file descriptor (resource) back to the operating system'. It was a stupid mistake, which I won't repeat again. I now always use the `with` statement.

Thanks, @Reductio and @Davis Herring for your help!